# WordPress : Form data is not displaying via echo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a form to which I am passing the data. When I try to echo the data it shows couple of errors saying that index is undefined.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Dummy Practice Page*/?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content-inner">
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input id="name" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="5" placeholder="Name" required><br>
                <input id="designation" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="50" placeholder="Designation" required><br>
                <input id="description" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="1000" placeholder="Description" required><br>
                <input id="pic" type="file" style="height:30px; width: 350px; "><br><br>
                <input name="insert" type='submit' style="height:40px; width: 130px; padding:10px; color:dodgerblue; background-color:black; border-radius:20px;    " name='Submit' value='Add Member' /><br><br>

            </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    echo $namevar = isset($_POST['name']);
    echo $descriptionvar = isset($_POST['description']);
    echo $designationvar = isset($_POST['designation']);
}
?>
```

**Following are the errors:**

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen-child\practicepage.php
>   Notice: Undefined index: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen-child\practicepage.php
>   Notice: Undefined index: designation in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen-child\practicepage.php

Comment: you not mentioned <input name="name" type="text" />

Comment: See: `<input type="submit">` have two `name`(s)

Comment: @STBox try with my updated answer?

Comment: Yup Sir thats not working too

Comment: @STBox you have two names in <input name="insert" name="Submit" type='submit'/>

Comment: Sorry its a tryping mistake here. I have changed it but still page not found errror

Comment: @STBox see my updated answer

Comment: OK now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input name="name" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="5" placeholder="Name" required><br>
                <input name="designation" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="50" placeholder="Designation" required><br>
                <input name="description" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="1000" placeholder="Description" required><br>
                <input id="pic" type="file" style="height:30px; width: 350px; "><br><br>
                <input name="insert" type='submit' style="height:40px; width: 130px; padding:10px; color:dodgerblue; background-color:black; border-radius:20px;" value='Add Member' /><br><br>

    </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    echo $namevar = $_POST['name'];
    echo $descriptionvar = $_POST['description'];
    echo $designationvar = $_POST['designation'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I have changed it but its still not working
showing error on   echo $namevar = $_POST['name'];

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen-child\practicepage.php

Comment: can you use if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){-----}

Comment: I have edited my question as you said, now it is giving page not found error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the names of input fields.
In PHP or any other programming language, You should use the input name="something" to get the input values.

You should give the name for each input fields. 
For example,

`<input name = "name" id="name" type="text" style="height:30px; width: 350px; " maxlength="5" placeholder="Name" required><br>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass POST data to another page vie using `ID`.

You should give `name` to `<input>`

```
<input name="name">
<input name="description">
<input name="designation">
```

**Edit**

You are defining variables and echoing them same time

Change your code to:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["insert"])){
  echo $_POST["name"];
  echo $_POST["description"];
  echo $_POST["designation"];
}?>
```

Comment: it should be if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){...}

Comment: @MohitKumar both are wrong, what if `isset($_POST["Submit"])=1` and `isset($_POST["name"])=0`?? It will show same error again.